# Access to methods of UI5 control instance from View

Tags: sapui5

I am a newbie programming in SAP UI5, and using the `sap.m.Tree` object I have had the need to access some of its properties from the view. But I think this is not possible without making changes in the model.

The tree object allows to feed it with a JSONModel that has nodes in the form of hierarchy, it is only necessary to relate parent and child in a very simple type structure:

```json
{
    "text": "Node1",
    "nodes": [
        {
            "text": "Node1-1",
            "nodes":[ "..." ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Once the tree is created, the component generates extra information such as whether the element is a leaf (it has no children), whether in which level the item is, etc. data that I do not have in the model.

At the time of using it in the view, in this way

```xml
<Tree id="Tree" items="{/}">
    <StandardTreeItem title="{text}" mode="Active"/>
</Tree>
```

I need, for example, to change mode from `"Active"` to `"Navigation"` only for nodes that are leaf, but I think it is not possible to access the sap.m.StandardTreeItem own methods like `isLeaf()`, `isTopLevel()` or `getLevel()`.

My idea was to use it in an expression like

```xml
<StandardTreeItem title="{text}" mode="{= ${this.isLeaf()} ? 'Navigation' : 'Active' }" />
```

I also tried with a `formatter` but I think the only thing it passes as a parameter is the value of the field.

Is there any way to do this? Or the only way is that the model has already calculated an attribute with `"leaf": true`, when it is leaf?

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1072

Comment: @Cmdd It fails to load the file of the format that is in "project1/model/format.js":

Error found in View (id: 'container-project1---View1').
XML node: '<StandardTreeItem xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" title="{name}" core:require="{ format: 'project1/model/format' }" type="{path:'name' , formatter:'format' }" press="onItemPress"/>':
ModuleError: failed to load 'project1/model/format.js' from resources/project1/model/format.js: script load error

Comment: What version of SapUI5 are you using?

Comment: SAPUI5: "1.92.0"

Comment: thanks @Cmdd I finally managed to fix the error, [running example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DOjPFh0npWbAAPf5)